# Django rest response to display full dependencies structures and data

Tags: python, json, django, rest, serialization

I have made Django REST function based API. I want to generate response to display full dependencies structure and data.

Employee is onetoone relation with User and Foreignkey to Company.
The response should show Employee data with User and Company related data.

Below is my code excerpts

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/api.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_employee(request):
    return Response(Employee.objects.all().values(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    identity_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

current result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 8,
    "company_id": 3,
    "identity_number": "",
    "tel": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "address_zip": "",
    "address_city": "",
    "address_state": "",
    "address_country": "",
    "face_image": "",
    "created_at": "2017-11-12T15:35:19.427973Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-12T15:35:19.455553Z"
  },
  {
  ....
```

what i am trying to achieve is this. how to do this result ? kind of like presenter on ruby on rails.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user": 
           {"id": 1,
            "username": "michaeljackson",
            "first_name": "michael",
            "last_name": "jackson",
            "email": "xxx@gmail.com"},
    "company": 
           {"id": 2,
            "name": "company X",
            "tel": "123456",
            ....},
    "identity_number": "",
    "tel": "",
    "address_1": "",
    "address_2": "",
    "address_zip": "",
    "address_city": "",
    "address_state": "",
    "address_country": "",
    "face_image": "",
    "created_at": "2017-11-12T15:35:19.427973Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-12T15:35:19.455553Z"
  },
  {
  ....
```

Comment: U'd better use drf (django-restful-framework), and write related serializer to each model. Then you are able to define the structure by combining different serializers.

Comment: I am already using DRF, and its just function based.

Comment: Then write a to_dict method inside of the class, which returns a dict object, and you can nest the dict with different attributes which also has a to_dict method

Comment: @Axil you may want to browse DRF's doc - this might be a good starting point: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: thanks will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are various ways to do that. One of them could be to create as_dict() for you model which will return a dictionary . You can add whatever fields you need in that dictionary.

Assuming you have following Company model.

```
class Company:
     name = model.CharField(max_length)
     domain = model.CharField(max_length)

     def as_dict(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'domain': self.domain}
```

for User class you can add as_dict as follows

```
def user_as_dict(self):
      return {"first_name": self.first_name}

User.add_to_class('as_dict', user_as_dict)
```

as_dict for Employee model:

```
def as_dict(self):
    {"company": self.company.as_dict(),
     "user": self.user.as_dict(), 
    "identity_number": self.identity_number}
```

And finally you can change response in view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_employee(request):
    data = [emp.as_dict() for emp in Employee.objects.all()]
    return Response({"results": data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: thanks. as for User class, how do i define it, as you can see, User is by default so its not defined. How can i put user_as_dict(self) definition and where ? currently its like this https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

Comment: I guess User is coming from django, you do not need to define that.

Comment: this error appears "'User' object has no attribute 'as_dict'"

Comment: https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py this is my latest as_dict changes

Comment: you have not placed user as_dict in models. place 
`def user_as_dict(self):
      return {"first_name": self.first_name}

User.add_to_class('as_dict', user_as_dict)`

Comment: but where should I place this ? as my User model is using the default User model. Do i put that in Employee model ?

Comment: i put it at the end of the models.py file, the result is an array of NULL

Comment: Just place before definition of Company class starts. above line number 16

Comment: the result is also same. array of NULL. https://imgur.com/a/sLuxd. I'ved checked in the code as your latest instructions in https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/models.py

Comment: is the null caused by this query https://gitlab.com/firdausmah/railercom/blob/master/railercomapp/api.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159043/discussion-between-axil-and-navyad).